# Extracting a number and reinserting it using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that contains lines like this:

```xml
    <testsuites tests="12" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="3" ...
    <testsuites tests="13" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" ...
    <testsuites tests="14" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="14" ...
    <testsuites tests="9" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="9" ...
```

I want to replace the number for failures with the number for errors so the file looks like this:

```xml
    <testsuites tests="12" failures="3" disabled="0" errors="3" ...
    <testsuites tests="13" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" ...
    <testsuites tests="14" failures="14" disabled="0" errors="14" ...
    <testsuites tests="9" failures="9" disabled="0" errors="9" ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this on the shell with sed or a similar tool.

EDIT:
I reformulated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Where by any number you mean? I presume a number in a bash variable?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want the line ´<testsuites tests="10" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="3" ...´ to be replaced with  ´<testsuites tests="10" failures="3" disabled="0" errors="3" ...´

Comment: @bgp2000, please do add your efforts which you have put to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
num=4 #for example
sed "s/failures=\"0\"/failures=\"$num\"/g" filename
```

A simple substitution.

UPDATE:

```
sed "s/failures=\"0\"\(.*\)errors=\"\(.*\)\"/failures=\"\2\"\1errors=\"\2\"/g" filename
```

Comment: The number Y won't be constant for the whole file. It will differ for each line. My problem is that I don't know how to extract Y for each line and reinsert it into the same line.

Comment: @bgp2000, can you please tell me how you obtain that “Y”? Like is it the line number, or is that “Y” stored somewhere?

Comment: @bgp2000, check it now. Although i guess i made it way too untidy.